# Object array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I encountered several problems when creating storing objects to an Array and printing in c# after debugging. What is my problem here? The problem started occurring at adding the objects to the Array and printing the object title.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ComputerGame cg1 = new ComputerGame("Age of Empires",49.99);
        Console.WriteLine(cg1.title);

        ComputerGame cg2 = new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00);
        ComputerGame cg3 = new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50);
        ComputerGame[] gameAlbum = new ComputerGame[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
        {
            gameAlbum[0] = new ComputerGame();
            gameAlbum[1] = new ComputerGame();
            gameAlbum[2] = new ComputerGame();
        }
        foreach(ComputerGame o in gameAlbum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.title);
        }
    }

public class ComputerGame
{
    public string title;
    public double price;
    public ComputerGame(string title, double price)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;

    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem in code?

Comment: you're not putting the cg1, cg2 and cg3 to the array object gameAlbum. by reading i think when you run you're code you get a null pointer error.

Comment: You are creating objects correctly, but then you are recreating gameObjects with default constructor in forloop, that means all the members of a class are null. Sign and create instances individually one by one like you did before the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ComputerGame cg1 = new ComputerGame("Age of Empires",49.99);
    Console.WriteLine(cg1.title);

    ComputerGame cg2 = new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00);
    ComputerGame cg3 = new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50);
    ComputerGame[] gameAlbum = new ComputerGame[5];

    gameAlbum[0] = cg1;
    gameAlbum[1] = cg2;
    gameAlbum[2] = cg3;

    foreach(ComputerGame o in gameAlbum)
    {
        if (o != null)
           Console.WriteLine(o.title);
    }

    double total = gameAlbum.Where(g => g != null).Sum(g => g.price);
}
```

Simpler way using a list instead of an array:

```
List<ComputerGame> games = new List<ComputerGame>();
games.Add(new ComputerGame("Age of Empires", 49.99));
games.Add(new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00));
games.Add(new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50));
games.Add(new ComputerGame("Portal", 19.50));
games.Add(new ComputerGame("Portal 2", 29.50));

foreach(ComputerGame game in games)
{
    if (game != null)
        Console.WriteLine($"Title: {game.title}, Price: {game.price}");
}

double total = games.Sum(p => p.price);
```

Comment: lets say i want to display the total price in the objects how would i do that?

Comment: For that I'd ask a separate StackOverflow question :-)

Comment: @J.Koh for sum of the computers..try this way..                                                                                                                                           double total = games.Sum(p => p.price);

Comment: @PrasadRaja it throws a null pointer reference after i added double total = gameAlbum.Sum(p => p.price);

Comment: @J.Koh i added new answer...check it

Comment: where do you put it? put it after the loop.

Comment: yeah i put it after the loop @Dr.Stitch

Comment: do still get the error? you're using array object or list?

Comment: yes i do. I am still using array object and didnt change any of the codes. The error thrown shows this : An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ComputerGameApp.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: use this code => double total = gameAlbum.Where(g => g != null).Sum(g => g.price); it will exclude all the null objects.

Comment: Yes it work! I guess it is because the program crashed when the program runs and pointed to a null value in the memory and the null pointer exception is thrown. Thanks for the prompt reply and solution! Appreciated! (: @Dr.Stitch

Answer (score 1):

Remove for loop. Create instances with parameters like you did. Sign it to array like gameObjs[0] = cg1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Gamealbum 0, 1 and 2 are created with a parameterless constructor but you require two parameters.

Try addimg another constructor to your class or include the parameters in the new-statements.

On a sidenote, there is no reason to loop 5 times since the loop just does tje same thing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
ComputerGame cg1 = new ComputerGame("Age of Empires",49.99);
ComputerGame cg2 = new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00);
ComputerGame cg3 = new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50);

ComputerGame[] gameAlbum = new ComputerGame[5];
gameAlbum[0] = cg1;
gameAlbum[1] = cg2;
gameAlbum[2] = cg3;

foreach(ComputerGame o in gameAlbum)
{
    if (o != null)
        Console.WriteLine(o.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ComputerGame[] gameAlbum = new ComputerGame[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
        {
            gameAlbum[0] = new ComputerGame();
            gameAlbum[1] = new ComputerGame();
            gameAlbum[2] = new ComputerGame();
        }
```

In the for loop, you are initiating the first three elements of array again and again. You are also calling the default constructor of `ComputerGame` class. So `title` element of `ComputerGame` won't get initialized. So you won't see anything printed on console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the default constructor for ComputerGame is overridden. There is no constructor such as:

```
public ComputerGame()
{...
}
```

Hence, you can do as follows:

```
gameAlbum[0] = new ComputerGame("Age of Empires",49.99);
gameAlbum[1] = new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00);
gameAlbum[2] = new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50);
```

You might also get errors as you are making use of only 3 of the 5 array elements. Hence, use List<> instead of arrays for dynamically creating the objects when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any assignments to the array "gameAlbum" in your for loop.
Try the below one and see.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ComputerGame[] gameAlbum = new ComputerGame[3];

    gameAlbum[0] = new ComputerGame("Age of Empires",49.99);
    gameAlbum[1] = new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00);
    gameAlbum[2] = new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50);

    foreach(ComputerGame o in gameAlbum)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(o.title);
    }
}

public class ComputerGame
{
    public string title;
    public double price;
    public ComputerGame(string title, double price)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code..

Looping the data & get sum of the price

```
         ComputerGame[] gameAlbum = new ComputerGame[5];
        gameAlbum[0] = new ComputerGame("Age of Empires", 49.99);
        gameAlbum[1] = new ComputerGame("Heroes and Generals", 30.00);
        gameAlbum[2] = new ComputerGame("Team Fortress 2", 19.50);
        gameAlbum[3] = new ComputerGame("Portal", 19.50);
        gameAlbum[4] = new ComputerGame("Portal 2", 29.50);

        //looping the data
        foreach (ComputerGame item in gameAlbum)
        {
            if (item != null)
                Response.Write("Name : " + item.title + " Price : " + item.price);
        }
        //get the sum of the price
        double total = gameAlbum.Sum(p => p.price);
        Response.Write(total);
```

Comment: is it possible to use just arrays instead of list?

Comment: you means  instead of List<ComputerGame>  ? you want to make it as array ?

Comment: the original code uses array object. the List<ComputerGame> is just a suggestion by @gotnull.

Comment: i updated the code to array.. it this is useful mark this as answer